# Looking for real time video streaming/editing software for commercial snips

Tags: video-editor, streaming

As the title says i am looking for a video editing/playing software for commercial snips, etc.

I should be able to:

- Add video files to a "queue"
- Play this "queue" in a loop
- Reorder video files while the "queue" is playing
- If possible, display images for a chosen duration
- If possible, be able to keep track of which video snips belong to a customer
- If possible, be able to keep track of how much a video clip is played during a period of time (total time)

This will be used to sell and play commercial snips on big screens/projectors.

Can you recommend a suitable software that fulfills these requirements?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Any decent software media player can do this. I'd recommend [Potplayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/).

It has a playlist module --> that's your 'queue'. It has a repeat playlist feature --> that's your loop. And you can add/remove/shuffle the entries in the playlist during playback. Potplayer can display still images but it defaults to a duration of 10 seconds. Not aware if that can be changed. You can duplicate the image entry in the playlist to have a play duration in multiples of 10 seconds. And you can get a custom duration by using ffmpeg to create a video of the still image like this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i imagefile -t 01:45 imagevideo.mp4
```

(1 minute, 45 seconds in the above example).

Use the 32-bit static build of ffmpeg from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

The other logging/auditing features are probably not possible with regular media players out of the box. Digital signage softwares probably have them.